# Multiset Covers with a Uniformity Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, multisets, hypergraphs

I was playing around with the indices of tuples of functions, and these objects came up naturally. Is there a name for them? Are there any resources on them that provide some properties or even a classification?

Let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq P([n])$. It has the property that there exists a multiset $\widetilde{\mathcal{A}}$ with elements in $\mathcal{A}$ such that every $i\in [n]$ is in exactly $k$ elements of $\widetilde{\mathcal{A}}$, counted with multiplicity.

Say $\cal{A}=\{S_1 ,\ldots, S_m\}$. I've shown that this roughly corresponds to the binary matrix $[\varepsilon_{i,j}]$, where $\varepsilon_{i,j}=1$ if and only if $i\in S_j$, such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \varepsilon_{1,1} & \dots  & \varepsilon_{1,m}\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \varepsilon_{n,1} & \dots  & \varepsilon_{n,m} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
    l_1\\
    \vdots\\
    l_m
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    1\\
    \vdots\\
    1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has a solution for some nonnegative rational-entried vector $[l_i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hypergraph is a generalisation of a graph where each (hyper)edge can connect an arbitrary number of vertices. If we view the elements of $[n]$ as vertices, then $\mathcal A$ is a multiset of hyperedges and $\widetilde{\mathcal A}$ is a **$k$-regular hypergraph**.

Without further restrictions such hypergraphs are very easy to generate – simply pick for each vertex the $k$ hyperedges that contain it.

Comment: Thanks! Based on Wikipedia, it might be more complete to call it a $k$-regular multi-hypergraph (or hyper-multigraph?)